# Why is my SELECT statement returning the database name as a column name?! (new to pdo)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Hi and thanks for reading.

I'm new to php (but I've been programming for a long time now) so I decided to use the pdo interface as a starter for my database queries. I did put a small script to test but it returns the database name as one of the columns name. Why?

Also for you pdo pros, once I instanciated a new pdo object without specifying the database name, how can I select it to prevent writing "databaseName.tableName" in my queries... See my script below:

        

`try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage() . '
';
    echo 'N° : ' . $e->getCode();
    die();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myTest DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
$sth->execute();

$sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTest.user(
                    personID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    PRIMARY KEY(personID),
                    FirstName varchar(15),
                    LastName varchar(15),
                    Age int(3)
                    )");
$sth->execute();

$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTest.user (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$sth->execute(array("Charles", "Gagnon", "28"));

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM myTest.user");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($result);
print_r($json);

?>`

So yeah, the print_r outputs this json:

```
{"personID":"1","FirstName":"Charles","user":"28"}
```

Pretty weird, it outputs the name of the table (user) instead of "Age" and the LastName field isn't there at all...

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your database contains the data you're expecting?

Comment: @deceze - Yeah ok, fair enough. But, a database not containing the information requested is no reason (as far as I am aware) for it to return the Database name as one of the column names.

Comment: Point being that perhaps you have created the database incorrectly before in previous iterations of your script and have never purged it. All your `CREATE` queries are `IF NOT EXISTS` only, so they won't overwrite old versions unless you do so explicitly yourself.

Comment: @deceze What gets me is the lack of `LastName` and `Age` fields in the result. The `INSERT` statement should have thrown an exception if those columns were not present.

Comment: @Charles are you sure you're executing the right script? Could you be looking at the wrong copy?

Comment: @Phil Brown, Yeah it it the good script. I can't believe how much time I wasted with this but I realised after your comment that it works just fine in the browser... The wrong output came from the Zend Debugger/eclipse combination. I don't know why this happens but it works so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot replicate this. Using your exact code, I get

```
{"personID":"1","FirstName":"Charles","LastName":"Gagnon","Age":"28"}
```

<strike>Are you sure the `myTest` database and table `user` do not already exist with a different schema to what you're expecting (yet somehow still working for the `INSERT` statement)?</strike>

*Edit: There's no way your insert statement would work if the schema was different.*

> Also for you pdo pros, once I instanciated a new pdo object without specifying the database name, how can I select it to prevent writing "databaseName.tableName"

Just re-instate the PDO object, specifying the `dbname` parameter in the DSN. Otherwise, I suppose you could try executing a `use <database>;` command.

Comment: @deceze @J.T.S - Well I don't get it. I'm dropping the database in phpMyAdmin each time but I think it would produce an error anyway without the IF NOT EXISTS. I debugged it countless times now and I alway get the same thing, the associative array indeed contains only 3 pairs and one of them is "user" => 28

Comment: Brown - Thanks for the "use database" command, it solves that problem. It's interesting that you get the 4 desired pairs with the code. On my side, the fetch statement only returns 3 pairs. Just one of these days when you fancy throwing you laptop off a cliff for me I guess.

Comment: No - don't 'USE database', explicitly reference the database in the query....INSERT INTO dbname.tablename / SELECT...FROM dbname.tablename - if you start working with multiple database you're code will get in a mess with 'USE'

Comment: @symcbean I get the feeling the OP's only interested in using the one database. He would have added it to the DSN if he didn't need to first create it.